# Vim how to autosave and get autocmds to run

Tags: vim

I have the following in my .vimrc to autoformat my python code on save.

`autocmd BufWritePost *.py silent !autopep8 --in-place --aggressive %`

However I am using a plugin [vim-auto-save](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-auto-save) that automatically saves my code for me. However the `BufWritePost` event doesn't seem to get called. I have to manually run `:w` for my `autocmd` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Vim-auto-save runs a

> silent! wa

command, which should save all files, and that should trigger the BufWritePost event.

Did you enable [vim-auto-cmd](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-auto-save) on startup?

> let g:auto_save = 1  " enable AutoSave on Vim startup

Comment: yes, autosave is working perfectly. I just cant get my autocmd to trigger.

Comment: You might want to check some other obvious things, like is VIm able to run autopep8 (since you have silent mode enabled for vim-auto-save, and some error messages could be hidden because of this). Or put the whole autopep8 command between quotemarks...

Comment: i turned off silent mode, the autocmd doesn't run at all

Comment: `:autocmd` do not nest by default. You will need to use the `nested` option for the vim-auto-save's `:autocmd` or modify the plugin to to trigger `BufWritePost` via `:doautocmd`. Please see `:h autocmd-nested` for more information.

Comment: nested is the answer. Please answer the question and I will accept your answer.